# PostgreSQL - Which film category is the most popular among our customers?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to answer a specific question "Which film category is the most popular among our customers?" I have this query to modify:

```html
SELECT  f.title, COUNT(*) AS RentalCount
  FROM  film f
    INNER JOIN film_category fc ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
    INNER JOIN category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
    INNER JOIN inventory i ON i.film_id = f.film_id
    INNER JOIN rental r ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
  WHERE (c.name = 'Sports')
  GROUP BY f.title
  ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

[This is the ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHS1f.png)

Thank you!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close with your query.  Basically, you just need to aggregate by the category:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) AS RentalCount
FROM film_category fc JOIN
     category c
     ON c.category_id = fc.category_id JOIN
     inventory i
     ON i.film_id = fc.film_id JOIN
     rental r
     ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY RentalCount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm getting a syntax error at line 3 though (category c) do you know how come?